# Pitch transpose with AudioToolbox AudioUnit samplerUnit

Tags: xcode, coremidi

This "Pitch Transposing" test code is not working with AudioUnit samplerUnit.
Sending the same MIDI messages thru MIDI Out to an external sound module, it works perfect. What do I wrong. I can't use "Pitch Bend" for this case. Is the controller "0x06" eventually not implemented in the API?

```
- (void) demoTranspose {

    [at0 setInstrument :0x11 :0x00];

    [at0 midiEvent :0xB0 :0x65 :0x00];
    [at0 midiEvent :0xB0 :0x64 :0x02];

    [at0 midiEvent :0x90 :0x3C :0x7F]; // Note ON
    usleep(1000000);

    [at0 midiEvent :0xB0 :0x06 :0x40+6];  // 40: center, +6 semi tones higher
    usleep(1000000);

    [at0 midiEvent :0xB0 :0x06 :0x40+12];  // 40: center, +12 semi tones higher
    usleep(1000000);

    [at0 midiEvent :0x90 :0x3C :0x00]; // Note OFF

    [at0 midiEvent :0xB0 :0x06 :0x40]; // reset to center

}

- (void) midiEvent :(Byte)statusInfoA :(Byte)param1A :(Byte)param2A {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (self.samplerUnit, statusInfoA, param1A, param2A, 0);
}
```

Comment: I know this is old but maybe it has something to do with your sampler AU, have you checked that yet?

Comment: Thanks, but what means "something to do with my sampler AU"?
I use the sampler AU, and all other things are working.
After several mails with the Apple developer support, they wrote: It must be a bug, please write a bug report. Since writing the bug report ---> silence.

Comment: I assume you wrote your own sampler audio unit code and if you did I would check how you are parsing the MIDI input pitch bend message

Comment: As the normal "pitch bend" is working, it must be a bug in the API.

Comment: As the normal "pitch bend" is working, it must be a bug in the API.
The code I use is listed on the top of this page. I could send you a sample project, if you give me a mail address, thanks.
By the way, is there a possibility to increase the maximum simultaneously sounding tones with the AU sampler? Some sounds are cut when MIDI files uses a lot of sounds simultaneously.